# .Bat file that opens 2 URLs in different browsers then click on button located on the each page

Tags: windows, firefox, command-line, internet-explorer, batch

I Would like to click on .Bat file that opens 2 URLs in different browsers (Firefox and IE) then click on button located on the each page (ex. Submit or login buttons) .

This is what I got so far in the bat file:

```
start iexplore https://www.yahoo.com    
start firefox https://www.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, .bat files aren't the best way to scrape or automate websites. Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to take a look at GreaseMonkey; a script engine extension for firefox. 
Another popular choice is to use python, which has multiple libraries available to parse html/xml (e.g. beautifulsoup), in addition to easy web interfaces to request and receive.
And if the goal is just to deal with email, these email services can return XML. For example, in gmail, to check your current status, you can issue this URL:

> https://username:password@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom

Where, username and password is your actual values. Also note the https instead of http.

Comment: Perhaps even an AutoHotKey/AutoIt script depending on requirements...